# 0x protocol - Using the qoute endpoint without takerAddress parameter

Tags: pancakeswap, 0x, nonce

I want to use the 0x quote api endpoint (https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote). When requesting a swap, i do not know the takerAddress since at request time i do not know from which account i am executing the swap. Is it possible to consume the quote response without takerAddress and how would i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill a quote even if the taker address is not specified on the quote. Filling the taker address and passing it on the API call will trigger additional validation and a more accurate gas estimation. However if you know how much gas the swap will cost and if the taker is eligible to fill the quote, the swap will succeed.